Using Kinect xbox one Vertically
I'm using this github repo: BodyScanner-Kinect i connect the kinect and it works perfectly with this github code, but i need to use the kinect vertically, so i need to change the code in the github link that i added. I checked the code, but i'm not sure which part of the code should i change to work with kinect vertically. If any one is familiar with C# and kinect can help me what should i change and which one of the files should i change to get the results correctly?
I run the code and it works but i want to use the kinect vertically, so i need to change the code to get the frames vertically.
